# Getter is not associated to any field - Realm

Tags: java, android, listview, android-recyclerview, realm

I am new to using **Realm library** and was trying to implement it in my android application. Just got stuck at a point where I am trying to section my **listview** based on the view type of a particular element in my **json response**.

I have tried to implement the sections with **`recycler view`** but the problem is I have 2 view types and addition of headers for those view types was causing an issue. Since **`Realm`** doesn't have the support of `RecyclerAdapter`, I created an implementation that will use a custom adapter that supports the RecyclerView.

So, I though I will use a `ListView` and try to use a simple interface for each of the Object type to determine the type and then insert the Headers based on the position of the group.

For some reason Realm is not allowing me to implement an interface in a class which extends `RealmObject`.

This is how that class looks like :

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import io.realm.RealmObject;
import io.realm.annotations.Ignore;
import io.realm.annotations.PrimaryKey;

    public class TestClass extends RealmObject implements Subjects {

        @PrimaryKey
        @SerializedName("subjectID")
        private String subjectID;

        private String subjectDate;

        @SerializedName("subjectDescription")
        private String subjectDescription;

        public String getSubjectID() {
            return subjectID;
        }

        public void setSubjectID(String subjectID) {
            this.subjectID = subjectID;
        }

        public String getSubjectDate() {
            return subjectDate;
        }

        public void setSubjectDate(String subjectDate) {
            this.subjectDate = subjectDate;
        }

        public String getSubjectDescription() {
            return subjectDescription;
        }

        public void setSubjectDescription(String subjectDescription) {
            this.subjectDescription = subjectDescription;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isSubjectA() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isFoo() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isBar() {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

And this is the **Compilation Error log** :

```
Error:(76, 20) error: Getter isSubject is not associated to any field.
Note: Creating DefaultRealmModule
Warning:File for type 'io.realm.DefaultRealmModule' created in the last round will not be subject to annotation processing.
Warning:File for type 'io.realm.DefaultRealmModuleMediator' created in the last round will not be subject to annotation processing.
2 warnings
```

I have no idea why is complaining about this issue but its not compiling the project.

I read a few discussion about the issue here : [link](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/952) .. Apparently, there's an open discussion about this issue but any other help will be really appreciated.. Thank you

Comment: I guess it assumes that isSubject should look for a subject property. Can you try with isIsSubject instead?

Comment: Hmm.. it would be very strange if it will work but I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Not working as expected but not sure what the actual reason might be. . :(

Comment: I think banabastard in his answer has a good point.

Comment: Its just a typo.. this is just a test example of the implementation. My bad

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an typo in your field's name, also it shouldn't have prefix, so it would be "sub**j**ect", and getter must be isSubject()

```
@Ignore
private boolean subject = false;


public boolean isSubject() {
    return subject;
}
```

[image: Valid XHTML]
.

Comment: Thank you for the efforts but the methods or variable names have nothing to do with the compilation failure. If the problem was with any of the naming conventions, it might happen in runtime. But the project itself is not compiling.

Comment: @mike20132013, i'm using realm in few projects and I assure you that it have.

Comment: Got it.. I have made an edit to the post but the thing is that those overrides are just a test variables. You can ignore them. The isSubject and the other 2 methods are basically used because I have to implement them and it only returns a boolean value. So basically the values in the current example class has nothing to do with the error I am getting now .. :(

Comment: I did upvote because of your efforts. I am understanding a bit now but @Ignore only works when you actually want to ignore a particular field in that class.

Comment: it doesn't matter that these variables are just for testing, because of you extending the  RealmObject class, all methods must be associated to some field (it can be @Ignored field). I have implementation of this in my project. And if I change field's or method's name, it wouldn't compile. Did you try just rename field correctly?

Comment: Dude.. ur a freaking life savior.. it did compile man.. no kidding. So basically, I had to add those variable names in the actual interface as well. And also, I used the same namespace in all the class implementation with the @Ignore. Thanks a ton man. But I actually wanna know how exactly it works. Can you lead me to some references ? That will be very helpful.

Comment: Yes, as i said in the beginning. For more info can see [issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/909) on github. And I think you should accept this answer.

Comment: I did actually went to that issue reference but wasn't getting the clue about the same name type. Thanks