# Realm object with RealmList

Tags: android, realm, realm-list

I'm beginner Realm programming and i need help.How i can create and insert RealmList inside Realm object? I wrote some codes and i have syntax error.
This is my main Realm object class

```
public class VinScannerHistoryModel extends RealmObject {
@Required
private String vinNumber;

@Required
private String userName;

@Required
private String status;


@Ignore
private RealmList<ImagesObject> imagesObjects;

public RealmList<ImagesObject> getImageList() {
    return imagesObjects;
}

public void setImageList(RealmList<ImagesObject> imageList) {
    this.imagesObjects = imageList;
}




@Required
private String key;


public String getPolygon() {
    return polygon;
}

public void setPolygon(String polygon) {
    this.polygon = polygon;
}

public String getKey() {
    return key;
}

public void setKey(String key) {
    this.key = key;
}

@Required
private String polygon;


public String getVinNumber() {
    return vinNumber;
}

public void setVinNumber(String vinNumber) {
    this.vinNumber = vinNumber;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}
```

}

This it a realmList class

```
public class ImagesObject extends RealmObject {
public String getImageName() {
    return imageName;
}

public void setImageName(String imageName) {
    this.imageName = imageName;
}
private String imageName;
```

}

I try to insert my DB like this

```
    private void insertIntoDatabase()
{
    mRealm.beginTransaction();

    ImagesObject imagesObject = mRealm.createObject(ImagesObject.class);
    VinScannerHistoryModel vinScannerHistoryModel = mRealm.createObject(VinScannerHistoryModel.class);
    vinScannerHistoryModel.setVinNumber(vinNumber.getText().toString());
    vinScannerHistoryModel.setStatus("Justsaved");
    if(Global.imagePath!=null && Global.imagePath.size()>0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Global.imagePath.size(); i++) {
            imagesObject.setImageName(Global.imagePath.get(i));
        }

        vinScannerHistoryModel.getImageList().add(imagesObject);
    }


    if(checkBox.isChecked())
        vinScannerHistoryModel.setKey("1");
    else
        vinScannerHistoryModel.setKey("0");
    vinScannerHistoryModel.setPolygon(polygonAdapter.getItem(spinnerPosition).getId()+"");



    vinScannerHistoryModel.setUserName(vinScannerModel.getName());
    mRealm.commitTransaction();
}
```

As i said I'm beginner Realm programming and i don't know is this correct way or not?
When i run my app I have this syntax error

```
Error:(31, 17) error: Setter setImageList is not associated to any field
```

How I can solve my syntax error and how i can insert some datas into RealmList?
if anyone knows solution please help me
thanks everyone

Comment: Remove the @Ignore before the imageObjects field

Comment: I removed it but i have same problem  in this method setImageList @MehmetKologlu

Comment: Rename it to match the field name, so 'setImageObjects'

Comment: Very Strange situation,I renamed it but now i have problem RealList setImageList method @  Mehmet Kologlu

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @Mehmet Kologlu i mean  i have same problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135309/discussion-between-mehmet-kologlu-and-baggio).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getter is not associated to any field - Realm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32564443/getter-is-not-associated-to-any-field-realm)

Comment: What version of Realm are you using? You shouldn't get `setImageList is not associated to any field` above 0.88.0

Comment: Using Realm 2.3.1 and copying your code, I do not see the error you describe.  I think your code will fail at `vinScannerHistoryModel.getImageList().add(imagesObject);` because the result of `getImageList` is probably null.  I also doubt that the for loop is doing what you intend (changing the name of a single object, several times, then inserting it)